# How to create pie chart in PowerShell with custom colors?

Tags: powershell, pie-chart

I have four values from results: Fail, Pass Crash and Progress.
I have two requirements where (1) I want to show fix colors with these four results (Ex: Red for fail, green = pass, yellow = progress and brown = Crash).
(2) The zero values should not show on pie chart. (Ex. if crash count is 0, do not show on chart).

$Cities is a Hashtable where values are fetched from Excel.

Name                           Value

---

Progress                       0
Crashed                        0
Failed                         2
Passed                         3

Here is my code:

Answer (score 0):

the following is glued together from the article [over at solarwinds](https://thwack.solarwinds.com/product-forums/network-performance-monitor-npm/f/forum/23620/pie-charts-using-powershell) and the info about palettes from [a blog entry](https://learn-powershell.net/2016/09/18/building-a-chart-using-powershell-and-chart-controls/). It takes the values from `$DataArray` and creates a pie chart from it. the section `chart colour palette` creates a custom colour palette which must match data array order to fulfill the mapping requirement.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization

$DataArray = @{Progress=0; Crashed=0; Failed=2; Passed=3}

# create chart object
$Chart = New-object System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart
$Chart.Width = 400
$Chart.Height = 400
$Chart.Left = 20
$Chart.Top = 20

# chart colour palette (must match data array order)
$chart.Palette = [System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartColorPalette]::None
$Chart.PaletteCustomColors = @( [System.Drawing.Color]::Brown,  [System.Drawing.Color]::Gold, [System.Drawing.Color]::Red, [System.Drawing.Color]::Green )

# create a chartarea to draw on and add to chart
$ChartArea = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea
$Chart.ChartAreas.Add($ChartArea)

# add data to chart
[void]$Chart.Series.Add("Data")
$Chart.Series["Data"].Points.DataBindXY($DataArray.Keys, $DataArray.Values)
$chart.Series["Data"].ChartType = "Pie"
$Chart.Series["Data"]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Outside"
$Chart.Series["Data"]["PieLineColor"] = "Black"
($Chart.Series["Data"].Points.FindMaxByValue())["Exploded"] = $true
$Chart.Series["Data"][?PieLabelStyle?] = ?Disabled?

# Legend
$Legend = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Legend
$Legend.IsEquallySpacedItems = $True
$Legend.BorderColor = 'Black'
$Chart.Legends.Add($Legend)
$chart.Series["Data"].LegendText = "#VALX (#VALY)"

# save chart to file
$Chart.SaveImage("c:\Temp\piechart.png", "PNG")
```